# Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed

Tags: magento2.2

I need some help after installing a third party theme I got this:

I've looked up for similar topics on the forum but since I'm a newbie I don't get exactly where to find and how to remove the 'after' attribute.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 723


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 723

#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('__construct('createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(141): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '\n   load(Array)
#9 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#10 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#11 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#13 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#14 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#15 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'mimosa4')
#16 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
#17 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#18 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#31 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#33 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#34 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#35 {main}
```

Comment: can you check : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11116

Answer (score 1):

Open the theme through any editor and look in the files with the `xml` type of the `referenceContainer` who have an `after` and delete it.